# how to use the proxy service without tryit tool in wso2 esb?

Tags: proxy, wso2, wso2-esb

I am learning and working on building some wso2 sample prototypes.

I have created a proxy service and tried using it with the **tryit** tool inside.

But i don't know how to use it externally. i mean how to send data to the proxy service because in API there is a endpoint created where the request is sent.

Is there anything like link to request or how to use it externally in some application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SOAP UI. Please check the [article](http://wso2.com/library/blog-post/2013/08/invoking-secured-esb-proxy-service-using-soap-ui/).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to call Your proxy service is to use some Rest Client on Your Browser. I use Add-On in Firefox (RestClient i think). U can create there whole request (json, xml), add headers, Authentications or Content Type. It should helps U to call any services in wso2.